# Help Installing phpMyAdmin on Linux Server

Tags: linux, installation, phpmyadmin

I constantly get this error when attempting to view `index.php` in the phpMyAdmin folder I have setup:

> Cannot start session without errors,
>   please check errors given in your PHP
>   and/or webserver log file and
>   configure your PHP installation
>   properly.

I am using subversion with three co-workers and I am trying to install this on my repository, which is at */svni3/myusername/intranet/* on our linux development server. I do have shell access so I would be able to install it somewhere else if that may be causing the problem.

My config.inc.php file looks like this (only the things I changed):

> $cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'blah';
>
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] =
>   'cookie';
>
> //$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] =
>   '*username*';
>
> //$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] =
>   '*password*';
>
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] =
>   'localhost';

Other helpful information???

When I ping localhost it works.
When I run the command "ls -l /var/lib/php":

`drwxrwx--- 2 root apache 4096 2009-04-17 02:31 session`

If there's anything else that may be helpful let me know; this has been plaguing me for a few hours now.

Comment: I'm also open to suggestions on some apps that I can try out for SQL querying. I've tried SQLyog which I happen to like. MySQL Workbench doesn't seem to be doing what I'd like it to do. Anything else I may be able to get easily?

Answer (score 0):

Check your error log. If you're running Apache on a Debian system the log is probably in `/var/log/apache2/`
The path is probably similar on other distributions.

Which user and group is your web server running as?

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with server configurations, but there's a folder called samba in /var/log/ that has a ton of log files in it. I think user is root and group is apache.